# Animated movie where a boy tries to climb beams/poles connected to a heaven-like floating island

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, cyborg

There is this movie I saw with my dad back when I was still small (like 13 years ago or something). It's a relatively old animated movie, probably Japanese but can't remember to be honest.

What I remember about the movie is that the main character is a young cyborg boy and he is living in a futuristic world with a floating island above his own world. The floating island is mysterious and heaven-like and is connected to the world with steel beams/poles. These beams/poles have a defence mechanism to ensure that no one climbs up to the island (something like a big spiky ring moving up and down the pole knocking off all that's on there).

All the boy wants is to make it up there someday and throughout the movie you can see him trying numerous times and failing over and over and getting hurt like losing an arm and fixing himself again and again. Next to this boy there is also a girl that cared for him, not sure whether it was sister or romantic interest.

Comment: It sounds a bit like "Battle Angel", but there the young cyborg is female, with a male love interest.

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew battle angel alita but I didn't know the 1993 original version. Thanks so much <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does indeed sounds like the 1993 anime adaptation of *[Battle Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_(OVA))*, or *Gunnm*.

> Shortly after, the cyborg, now called Gally, becomes interested in Yugo, a local boy who is performing maintenance work for Ido. After Ido returns home late that night, the following day Gally notices his injured arm, which he explains away as the result of a fall. After introducing herself to Yugo, he convinces her to go with him and the two leave just as Chiren arrives.

....

> High above the city, Yugo has started to walk on a Factory tube towards Zalem. Soon, a massive spiked ring comes hurtling down the tube, forcing him to jump to avoid it, but his feet are destroyed in the process. Gally reaches the base of the tube and prepares to follow Yugo, who has survived the first ring to come down, but has lost his feet.
>
> After emerging past the clouds, Yugo can clearly see Zalem. Gally, who has caught up with him, pleads with him to return. Yugo is still adamant about reaching Zalem, but Gally convinces him that they can find a way to live in Scrap Iron City together. Another ring comes hurtling down the tube and Gally's warning comes too late as Yugo is shredded by the ring and thrown into the air. Leaping after him, Gally manages to grab his remaining arm and use her knife to secure herself to the tube. His elbow joints cannot hold however and break loose, but not before Yugo is able to say goodbye, leaving Gally on the tube clutching his forearm....

### Trailer

### Yugo's death scene